# Socket closed, missed heartbeats from client Celery worker with RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I create Flask application server which allows on one endpoint to spawn Celery worker. On second you can apply task to a specific queue connected to worker.

Everything works fine until worker is not used for more than 2 minutes.
Then RabbitMQ logs message

```
rabbit_1         | 2018-12-29 15:51:21.573 [error] <0.30372.0> closing AMQP connection <0.30372.0> (172.18.0.1:50058 -> 172.18.0.4:5672):
rabbit_1         | missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
```

Stack trace from app

```
> [2018-12-29 16:51:26,526] ERROR in app: Exception on /sentiment [POST]
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
>     rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py",
> line 1598, in dispatch_request
>     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restplus/api.py",
> line 325, in wrapper
>     resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/views.py",
> line 84, in view
>     return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restplus/resource.py",
> line 44, in dispatch_request
>     resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/konrad/Documents/ubuntu-docs/python-dev/crypto-ticker-sentiment/sentinet/evaluation_server/routes/sentiment.py",
> line 25, in post
>     prediction = predict_sentiment(queue, text)   File "/home/konrad/Documents/ubuntu-docs/python-dev/crypto-ticker-sentiment/sentinet/evaluation_server/services/evaluation.py",
> line 17, in predict_sentiment
>     task_result = task.get()   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/result.py",
> line 224, in get
>     on_message=on_message,   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/async.py",
> line 188, in wait_for_pending
>     for _ in self._wait_for_pending(result, **kwargs):   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/async.py",
> line 255, in _wait_for_pending
>     on_interval=on_interval):   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/async.py",
> line 56, in drain_events_until
>     yield self.wait_for(p, wait, timeout=1)   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/async.py",
> line 65, in wait_for
>     wait(timeout=timeout)   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/rpc.py",
> line 63, in drain_events
>     return self._connection.drain_events(timeout=timeout)   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py",
> line 301, in drain_events
>     return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)   File
> "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py",
> line 103, in drain_events
>     return connection.drain_events(**kwargs)   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/amqp/connection.py",
> line 491, in drain_events
>     while not self.blocking_read(timeout):   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/amqp/connection.py",
> line 496, in blocking_read
>     frame = self.transport.read_frame()   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/amqp/transport.py",
> line 243, in read_frame
>     frame_header = read(7, True)   File "/home/konrad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/amqp/transport.py",
> line 426, in _read
>     raise IOError('Socket closed') OSError: Socket closed
```

I think that may be something with heartbeats from Celery worker or the RabbitMQ issue.
I added **--without-heartbeat** option on worker spawning but it didn't work.
Will disabling heartbeats on RabbitMQ help?

### Update

I found it on the RabbitMQ [doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html) page but it doesn't say how to achieve it.

> How to Disable Heartbeats Heartbeats can be disabled by setting the
>   timeout interval to 0 on both client and server ends.
>
> Alternatively a very high (say, 1800 seconds) value can be used on
>   both ends to effectively disable heartbeats as frame delivery will be
>   too infrequent to make a practical difference.
>
> Neither practice is recommended unless TCP keepalives are used instead
>   with an adequately low inactivity detection period

### Update 2

I added `heartbeat = 0` to **rabbitmq.conf** file and it still doesn't work.